# Need help in retrieving a selenium webdriver element text using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to read a web page using python, Selenium and Chrome and dont seem to be able to retrieve the content of a searched element.
Any help and pointers would be useful.

Here is an extract of the code I have written

```py
    thElements = header.find_elements(By.XPATH, "th")

    iPos = 1
    headArray = ['Risk Category']

    for thElement in thElements:
        iPos = iPos + 1
        print(thElement.text)
        print(thElement.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
        headArray.append(thElement.text.strip())
```

the innerHTML gets printed as (I am showing only 5 of the 7 elements retrieved. It retrieves 7 in all.)

```html
<div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="docmentView('TSK6277482')">28-Dec-2016</a>
</div>
<div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="docmentView('TSK6526019')">15-Jun-2017</a>
</div>
<div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="docmentView('TSK7087944')">19-Oct-2017</a>
</div>
<div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="docmentView('TSK7537802')">25-May-2018</a>
</div>
<div class="dataTables_sizing" style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">
    <a href="http://xxx.comp.org/project/secure/sap/forms/isr?stage=IMP&amp;projId=P127866" target="_new">31-Jan-2019</a>
</div>
```

print(thElement.text) does not give me anything. I would expect that I get the dates inside the `<a>` tags when printing thElement.text

Thanks for any pointers on this.

Comment: Further searches got me to understand that the div element of which the thElement is a part is hidden (the style attribute says so.). The text of a hidden element can be accessed using thElement.get_attribute('textContent') instead of thElement.text. Please see https://yizeng.me/2014/04/08/get-text-from-hidden-elements-using-selenium-webdriver/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Further searches got me to understand that the div element of which the thElement is a part is hidden (the style attribute says so.). The text of a hidden element can be accessed using thElement.get_attribute('textContent') instead of thElement.text.

Thanks to yizeng.me/2014/04/08/… for the information. Please visit the same for more examples.

The required code for completeness is:

```
    thElements = header.find_elements(By.XPATH, "th")

    iPos = 1
    headArray = ['Risk Category']

    for thElement in thElements:
        iPos = iPos + 1
        print(thElement.get_attribute('textContent'))
        print(thElement.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
        headArray.append(thElement.text.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see instead of sticking to [`th`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp) elements you could rather locate [`a`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)  elements which [`onclick` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp) contains `docmentView` text (and it's better to fetch [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) property value), the relevant code would be something like:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@onclick, 'docmentView')]")

for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("innerText"))
```

If you need the element locator to match only `th` elements children you could go for [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant) axis:

```
//th/descendant::a[contains(@onclick, 'docmentView')]
```

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)